# Access denied exception using C# / UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

The `execute()` function is linked to a button press.
The first time it is pressed - everything runs the way it should/
The second time is is pressed (within the same execution of the app; if I close and re-open it works fine) - on the `DeleteAsync` line I get this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I think something is staying open longer than it should, hence the error. But I'm not sure what is causing it exactly. If anyone can see from the code below what could be happening I would be most grateful:

```
private async void execute(string url)
{
    StorageFolder filesFolder = null;
    StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    if (await localFolder.TryGetItemAsync(DIRECTORY_NAME) != null)
    {
        filesFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync(DIRECTORY_NAME);
        await filesFolder.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete); // << THIS IS THE EXCEPTION LINE
    }

    if (await localFolder.TryGetItemAsync(DIRECTORY_NAME) == null)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => {
                repository.Clone(url, DIRECTORY_NAME);
            });
    }

    // This won't be called until task above finished running
    filesFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync(DIRECTORY_NAME);
    IEnumerable<StorageFile> files = await filesFolder.GetFilesAsync();
    addFiles(files);
}
```

Clone function:

```
void Repository::Clone(Platform::String^ url, Platform::String^ path)
{
    OutputDebugString(L"Clone ");
    OutputDebugString(url->Data());
    OutputDebugString(L" into ");
    char temp[1024];
    GetLocalPath(path, temp, 1024);
    OutputDebugStringA(temp);
    OutputDebugString(L"\n");

    char urlt[1024];
    wcstombs(urlt, url->Data(), 1024);

    git_clone_options clone_opts = GIT_CLONE_OPTIONS_INIT;
    git_checkout_options checkout_opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTIONS_INIT;

    // Set up options
    checkout_opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE;
    checkout_opts.progress_cb = on_checkout_progress;
    clone_opts.checkout_opts = checkout_opts;
    clone_opts.fetch_opts.callbacks.sideband_progress = on_sideband_progress;
    clone_opts.fetch_opts.callbacks.transfer_progress = on_fetch_transfer_progress;
    clone_opts.fetch_opts.callbacks.credentials = on_credentials_required;
    clone_opts.fetch_opts.callbacks.payload = this->native;

    // Start the cloning
    report_error(git_clone(&repo, urlt, temp, &clone_opts));
}
```

Comment: i have this error too, i though this error was for authentication , but i cant delete a file from my current local folder

Comment: maybe you are using files in the folder? outside of the scope of this snippet?

Comment: @slawekwin: I am using a Git clone function from another project (which is in C++) - I've put the code above; maybe you can see something that could be causing it?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is related to the `clone` method, but it's hard to tell. Try to replace it with some dummy file creation method to test. Also, maybe `addFiles` influences them, or some random method somewhere else?

Comment: If I remove those 3 lines at the bottom the error stays so I guess it rules out `addFiles`. If I replace the Task.Run with this, then it works without errors (but obviously the app doesn't work because I'm not cloning the git files): `await Task.Run(async () => { await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(DIRECTORY_NAME);  });`

Comment: Add some files to this folder just to make sure, but it seems it's specific to `git` (maybe it uses those files after creation or sets them readonly?). Maybe search for solution on how to delete `git` files from a program then