# C# Create file after StorageFile.DeleteAsync fails with 0x80070005 E_ACCESSDENIED

Tags: c#, storagefile

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988937/access-denied-exception-using-c-sharp-uwp) to mine, but unfortunately it did not have an answer.

I'm using the StorageFile class in C# to create, write, then delete a file repetitively. On my second iteration, it fails to create the file, returning an access denied error.

Here is a simple unit test I put together in Visual Studio 2015 to demonstrate the problem:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task DeleteTest()
{
    StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    byte[] array = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test data");

    int i = 1, max = 20;
    string phase = "not started";
    try
    {
        do
        {
            // create file
            phase = "creating";
            StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("test" /*,CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName*/);

            // write data to the file
            phase = "opening";
            System.IO.Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

            phase = "writing";
            await stream.WriteAsync(array, 0, array.Length);

            phase = "flushing";
            await stream.FlushAsync();

            // delete file
            phase = "deleting";
            await file.DeleteAsync();
        } while (++i <= max);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Assert.Fail("While '{0}' on iteration {1}: {2}", phase, i, e.Message);
    }
}
```

The Assertion above fires, reporting:

> While 'creating' on iteration 2: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

If anyone can let me know what I am doing wrong, I'd appreciate it. I'm at my wits end with this.

Comment: are you sure `await file.DeleteAsync();` has finished before next iteration of `await folder.CreateFileAsync`?

Comment: No I'm not. It 'seems' like it has not finished, because I'm getting the access denied error. But I would expect the 'await' operator to cause the program execution to wait until the file has been removed.

Comment: I think you should first `Dispose()` the System.IO.Stream object before deleting the file. It is recommended to clean up resources used by the object. This may also solve the issue of ACCESSDENIED.

Comment: Thanks crazyGamer. Disposing of my stream resolved my issue. Since this is my fist post, I'm looking for the mechanism to accept your answer. Thanks again, you saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: Let me add my answer as an actual one, instead of a comment. Thank you for wanting to accept my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain library features such as file stream access make use of **unmanaged resources**, that must be *properly cleaned up before the object handle can be destroyed*. This avoids situations such as when files are open in background even after the program is done executing and prevents them from being modifiable, etc.

In case of `System.IO` and related functionality, Microsoft [recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6) that you call the `Dispose()` or `Close()` method that does exactly that. In your case, it is most likely that the file cannot be deleted successfully since it is open via the `Stream` object.

Hence, adding `Dispose()` after `Flush()` on the `Stream` should resolve the problem.

NOTE: `Dispose()` automatically calls `Flush()`, so an explicit call is redundant.